# React Native Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

my first question here, I apologize for my English as a translator, Note: I'm Brazilian.
I'm developing an app and I was trying to implement a function to present the onboarding screen only on the first time of use

**Imports**

```
import React from 'react';
import react, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import OnboardingScreen from './src/screens/Onboarding/OnboardingScreen';
import LoginScreen from './src/screens/LoginScreen';
```

**Body**

```
const [isFirtsLaunch, setIsFirtsLaunch] = react.useState(() => {});
    useEffect(() => {
        AsyncStorage.getItem('alreadyLaunched').then((value) => {
            if (value == null) {
                AsyncStorage.setItem('alreadyLaunched', 'true');
                setIsFirtsLaunch(true);
            } else {
                setIsFirtsLaunch(false);
            }
        });
    }, []);
    useEffect(() => {
        if (isFirtsLaunch === null) {
            return null;
        } else if (isFirtsLaunch === true) {
            return (
                <NavigationContainer>
                    <AppStack.Navigator headerModel="none">
                        <AppStack.Screen
                            name="Onboarding"
                            component={OnboardingScreen}
                            options={{ headerShown: false }}
                        />
                        <AppStack.Screen
                            name="Login"
                            component={LoginScreen}
                            options={{ headerShown: false }}
                        />
                    </AppStack.Navigator>
                </NavigationContainer>
            );
        } else {
            <LoginScreen />;
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably return your JSX from your component and not return it from a useEffect (more info [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

```
    const [isFirtsLaunch, setIsFirtsLaunch] = react.useState(() => {});

    useEffect(() => {
       AsyncStorage.getItem('alreadyLaunched').then((value) => {
            if (value == null) {
                AsyncStorage.setItem('alreadyLaunched', 'true');
                setIsFirtsLaunch(true);
            } else {
                setIsFirtsLaunch(false);
            }
        });
    }, []);

    if (isFirtsLaunch === null) {
        return <></>;
    } else if (isFirtsLaunch === true) {
        return (
            <NavigationContainer>
                <AppStack.Navigator headerModel="none">
                    <AppStack.Screen
                        name="Onboarding"
                        component={OnboardingScreen}
                        options={{ headerShown: false }}
                    />
                    <AppStack.Screen
                        name="Login"
                        component={LoginScreen}
                        options={{ headerShown: false }}
                    />
                </AppStack.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
        );
    } else {
        return <LoginScreen />;
    }
```